# xclip error can't open display: :0 in pop os

Tags: linux, x-server, pop-os

```
>> xclip
Error: Can't open display: :0
```

$DISPLAY variable seems be correct but tried below command to set $DISPLAY properly and it didn't work.

`export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0`

Note : I'm trying this in my local machine using PoP OS in hybrid mode(utilizing both integrated and external graphics). This seems to affect the functionality of pasting image in multiple applications but copy-pasting text seems to be working fine. xclip is failing for when trying in terminal.

Comment: Don't post images when plain text will do. Update the question with proof that running other X applications from that same prompt work. Also tell us whether you are running it locally or are you logged in from another system.

Comment: Thanks, Bib. Have done some edit based on your suggestions.